# How do I perform Casting with TypeTokens in Java?

Tags: java, casting, typetoken

I am passing a `TypeToken` to a method.  The code below works but I am afraid that by not explicitly defining `Object list` as something more specific is going to haunt me later but I cannot find a way to define it as or cast it as anything else without getting a compiler error or warning.  I seems like there should be a way to do something like `(listTypeToken.getType()) list = ...`

Here is is the code defining the `TypeToken`:

```java
 TypeToken<List<ServerInfo>> listTypeToken =  new TypeToken<List<ServerInfo>>(){};
```

Here is the code where I am using the `TypeToken`.  I think `Object list` should be casted as something more specific.

```java
public static <T> void processJson(GsonBuilder gsonBuilder, 
                                   String jsonString, 
                                   String action, 
                                   TypeToken<T> listTypeToken)
{
    //Trimmed from brevity
    Object list = gson.fromJson(jobject.get(action).getAsJsonArray(),
                                listTypeToken.getType());
}
```

Here is one of the other successful approaches but I'm not sure if it's the appropriate course:

```java
@SuppressWarning("rawtypes")
List list = gson.fromJson(jobject.get(action).getAsJsonArray(),
                                listTypeToken.getType());
```

Comment: Can't you make it List<ServerInfo> list = gson.fromJson(jobject.get(action).getAsJsonArray(),
                                listTypeToken.getType()); ?

Comment: The ServerInfo is just one of the about 50 classes that could be passed.  It was actually that kind of static coding what I was trying to get away from with the TokenType coding so I could push the process to a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fromJson` returns a `T` so the correct way would be this:

```
T list = gson.fromJson(jobject.get(action).getAsJsonArray(),
                                listTypeToken.getType());
```

If you are sure that `T` always is a subtype of `List`, then you need to provide a constraint in the declaration of the method:

```
public static <T extends List<?>> void processJson(...)
```

Or possibly this, which lets you work with the elements of the `List`:

```
public static <E, T extends List<E>> void processJson(...)
```